Exploring the options Parameter in UIPasteboard's setItems(_:options:) Method
I'm working on an iOS application where I need to use the clipboard functionality via UIPasteboard. I've come across the setItems(_:options:) method, which allows me to set multiple items to the pasteboard.
However, I'm unclear about the options parameter. Specifically, I would like to know:
What are the valid options I can pass to the options parameter?
How do these options affect the behavior of the pasteboard when setting items?
Any examples or documentation references would be greatly appreciated!

Did you check the documentation here?

When using the setItems(_:options:) method of UIPasteboard, the options parameter allows you to specify certain behaviors for how the items are set on the pasteboard. Here are the valid options you can pass:
UIPasteboard.OptionsName:
This parameter accepts an array of options that modify the behavior of the pasteboard. The most commonly used options are:
UIPasteboard.OptionsName.asynchronous:
This option allows setting items on the pasteboard asynchronously. When this option is specified, the method will return immediately, and the pasteboard will process the items in the background. This is useful for improving responsiveness in your app, especially when setting a large number of items.
UIPasteboard.OptionsName.expirationDate:
This option allows you to specify an expiration date for the items being set on the pasteboard. If you set an expiration date, the items will be removed from the pasteboard after this date.
UIPasteboard.OptionsName.name:
This option allows you to specify the name of the pasteboard if you are working with a custom pasteboard. This can be useful for creating named pasteboards for specific use cases.
